# ASP.net MVC AntiForgeryToken over AJAX

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, security

I am currently developing an MVC application in ASP.net. I am using AJAX.ActionLink to provide a delete link in a list of records, however this is very insecure. I have put this:

```
<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)>
```

Over the function to do the deleting, which stops the function being called simply by a URL. However, the other security hole that still exists is that if i were to make a basic html page with this content:

```
<form action="http://foo.com/user/delete/260" method="post">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

It would still be perfoming a post, but from a different location.

Is it possible to use the AntiForgeryToken with an AJAX ActionLink? If so, is this a secure approach? Are there more security holes i haven't realised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the AJAX ActionLink specifically, but it is possible from a WebForms page to post to an MVC action with the `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attributes.

You can use reflection to get at the MVC methods used to set the cookie and matching form input used for the MVC validation.

See this answer: [Using an MVC HtmlHelper from a WebForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347728/using-an-mvc-htmlhelper-from-a-webform/2553583#2553583)

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at this [blog post](http://blogs.us.sogeti.com/swilliams/2009/05/14/mvc-ndash-using-antiforgerytoken-over-ajax/).

> Say you have an Action method like
>   this:
>
> `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post),
>   ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
>   public ActionResult DeleteAccount(int
>   accountId) {
>       // delete stuff }`
>
> And you call it via:
>
> `$.post('/home/DeleteAccount', {
>   accountId: 1000 }, function() {
>       alert('Account Deleted.'); });`
>
> Since the POST does not include the
>   AntiForgeryToken, it will fail.
>
> Fortunately, it doesn’t take much
>   brainpower to fix this. All the client
>   side component of AntiForgeryToken
>   does is put the token in a basic
>   hidden field. So, you just need to
>   pull that data out and include it in
>   your AJAX call.
>
> `var token =
>   $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();`
>
> `$.post('/home/DeleteAccount', {
>   accountId: 1000,
>   '__RequestVerificationToken': token },
>   function() {
>       alert('Account Deleted.'); });`
>
> Do note that if you have multiple
>   forms on the page with multiple
>   AntiForgeryTokens, you will have to
>   specify which one you want in your
>   jQuery selector. Another gotcha is if
>   you are using jQuery’s
>   `serializeArray()` function, you’ll have
>   to add it a bit differently:
>
> `var formData =
>   $('#myForm').serializeArray(); var
>   token =
>   $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
>   formData.push({ name:
>   '__RequestVerificationToken', value:
>   token });`
>
> `$.post('/home/DeleteAccount',
>   formData, function() {
>       alert('Account Deleted.'); });`

Update: The link has been fixed.

Comment: You don't need formData.push({ name: '__RequestVerificationToken', value: token }); since serializeArray() will return all inputs in the form, that include __RequestVerificationToken hidden field.

Comment: Yes you do need this on AJAX posts (using current MVC 4 and MS unobtrusive AJAX = jQuery)!!!

Answer (score 6):

You can use AntiForgeryToken with Ajax.ActionLink but you need to manually insert the AntiForgeryToken into the header of your request like so:

```
function GetAntiForgeryToken(){
   var tokenWindow = window;
   var tokenName = "__RequestVerificationToken";
   var tokenField = $(tokenWindow.document).find("input[type='hidden'][name='" +     tokenName +   "']");
   if (tokenField.length == 0) {return null;}
   else {
      return {
         name: tokenName,
         value: tokenField.val()
      };
   }
};
```

Then, we can use $.ajaxPrefilter to insert it into the header:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(
   function (options, localOptions, jqXHR) {
      var token = GetAntiForgeryToken();
      jqXHR.setRequestHeader(token.name, token.value);
   }
);
```

I wrote a post about it [here](http://jonwhite.me/2012/09/16/how-to-use-antiforgery-tokens-with-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc/).  Hope this helps!

Comment: This does send the token in the header, but the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] filter requires this in the Form data...

Answer (score 6):

Use AntiForgeryToken with Ajax.ActionLink

In addition to **jjwhite01** response;
to insert the token in Form data, use `option.data` in Prefilter

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(
    function (options, localOptions, jqXHR) {
        if (options.type !== "GET") {
            var token = GetAntiForgeryToken();
            if (token !== null) {
                if (options.data.indexOf("X-Requested-With") === -1) {
                    options.data = "X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest" + (options.data === "") ? "" : "&" + options.data;
                }
                options.data = options.data + "&" + token.name + '=' + token.value;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: The unobtrusive ajax script in MVC 4 includes - options.data.push({ name: "X-Requested-With", value: "XMLHttpRequest" }) - so checking and adding for this is now unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used any ajax helpers myself, but I don't see any reason why you cannot use a link. Personally I would use an onload event handler to unobtrusively create a link from the form itself, and then remove the form.

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback on the `$.ajaxPrefilter` answers, I added the token to both `options` and `originalOptions` rather than the `jqXHR` headers. This does require the token to be somewhere in a form on your page.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]');
    if (token.length > 0) {
        var data = options.data;
        var dataArray = originalOptions.data;
        if (data && !data.includes('__RequestVerificationToken')) {
            options.data = data + '&__RequestVerificationToken=' + token.val();
        }
        if (dataArray && !('__RequestVerificationToken' in dataArray)) {
            var tokenObject = { name: '__RequestVerificationToken', value: token.val() };
            originalOptions.data.push(tokenObject);
        }
    }
});
```

Keep in mind that this will add this token to every single AJAX request on your page, so you may want to filter by the `options.url` string or `options.type == 'POST'`.