# Using an MVC HtmlHelper from a WebForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, html-helper

I'm in the process of adding some UI functionality to a hybrid WebForms/MVC site.  In this case, I'm adding some AJAX UI features to a WebForms page (via jQuery), and the data is coming from an MVC JsonResult.  Everything is working 100%, with one exception:

I would like to implement the XSRF protection of AntiForgeryToken.  I have used it in combination with the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute on my pure MVC applications, but would like to know how to implement the Html.AntiForgeryToken() method in WebForms.  [Here's an example using a UrlHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274319/access-htmlhelpers-from-webform-when-using-asp-net-mvc).

I'm having some trouble getting ViewContext / RequestContext "mocked" up correctly.  How should I go about using HtmlHelpers within a WebForms page?

**Edit**:
I'm looking to retrieve the AntiForgeryToken from my WebForms page, not from the MVC JsonResult.

Comment: I have the same problem - a legacy WebForms page that needs to post to an MVC action with an `AntiForgeryToken`. I want to add `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` to the WebForms page without rewriting it in MVC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key method is in the MVC source code: `GetAntiForgeryTokenAndSetCookie`

This creates an instance of an internal sealed class called `AntiForgeryData`.

The instance is serialised into a cookie "__RequestVerificationToken_" + a base 64 encoded version of the application path.

The same instance of `AntiForgeryData` is serialised into a hidden input.

The unique part of the `AntiForgeryData` is got with an `RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes()`

All of this could be spoofed in a WebForms page, the only messy bit is the serialisation of the hidden sealed class. Unfortunately the key method (`GetAntiForgeryTokenAndSetCookie`) relies on `ViewContext.HttpContext.Request` to get at the cookies, while the WebForm needs to use `HttpContext.Current.Request` instead.

---

**Update**

Not much testing and a lot of code, but I think I've cracked this with a little reflection. Where I've used reflection I've left the equivalent line commented out above:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

/// <summary>Utility to provide MVC anti forgery tokens in WebForms pages</summary>
public class WebFormAntiForgery
{
    /// <summary>Create an anti forgery token in a WebForms page</summary>
    /// <returns>The HTML input and sets the cookie</returns>
    public static string AntiForgeryToken()
    {
        string formValue = GetAntiForgeryTokenAndSetCookie();

        // string fieldName = AntiForgeryData.GetAntiForgeryTokenName(null);
        var mvcAssembly = typeof(HtmlHelper).Assembly;
        var afdType = mvcAssembly.GetType("System.Web.Mvc.AntiForgeryData");
        string fieldName = Convert.ToString(afdType.InvokeMember(
            "GetAntiForgeryTokenName",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            null,
            null,
            new object[] { null }));

        TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("input");
        builder.Attributes["type"] = "hidden";
        builder.Attributes["name"] = fieldName;
        builder.Attributes["value"] = formValue;
        return builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
    }

    static string GetAntiForgeryTokenAndSetCookie()
    {
        var mvcAssembly = typeof(HtmlHelper).Assembly;
        var afdType = mvcAssembly.GetType("System.Web.Mvc.AntiForgeryData");

        // new AntiForgeryDataSerializer();
        var serializerType = mvcAssembly.GetType("System.Web.Mvc.AntiForgeryDataSerializer");
        var serializerCtor = serializerType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
        object serializer = serializerCtor.Invoke(new object[0]); 

        // string cookieName = AntiForgeryData.GetAntiForgeryTokenName(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
        string cookieName = Convert.ToString(afdType.InvokeMember(
            "GetAntiForgeryTokenName",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            null,
            null,
            new object[] { HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath }));

        // AntiForgeryData cookieToken;
        object cookieToken;
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            // cookieToken = Serializer.Deserialize(cookie.Value);
            cookieToken = serializerType.InvokeMember("Deserialize", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, serializer, new object[] { cookie.Value });
        }
        else
        {
            // cookieToken = AntiForgeryData.NewToken();
            cookieToken = afdType.InvokeMember(
                "NewToken",
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                null,
                null,
                new object[0]);

            // string cookieValue = Serializer.Serialize(cookieToken);
            string cookieValue = Convert.ToString(serializerType.InvokeMember("Serialize", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, serializer, new object[] { cookieToken }));

            var newCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName, cookieValue) { HttpOnly = true };

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(newCookie);
        }

        // AntiForgeryData formToken = new AntiForgeryData(cookieToken)
        // {
        //     CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
        //     Salt = salt
        // };
        var ctor = afdType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { afdType });
        object formToken = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { cookieToken });

        afdType.InvokeMember("CreationDate", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, formToken, new object[] { DateTime.Now });
        afdType.InvokeMember("Salt", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, formToken, new object[] { null });

        // string formValue = Serializer.Serialize(formToken);
        string formValue = Convert.ToString(serializerType.InvokeMember("Serialize", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, serializer, new object[] { formToken }));
        return formValue;
    }
}
```

Usage is then similar to MVC:

```
WebFormAntiForgery.AntiForgeryToken()
```

It creates the same cookie and the same HTML as the MVC methods.

I haven't bothered with the salt and domain methods, but they would be fairly easy to add in.

Comment: Hi, I just tried to implement this in a webforms app (.NET 4.0, MVC 3.0) and got an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error from this line: 

var serializerCtor = serializerType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);

Can someone help? I'm a little out of my depth here.

Comment: @BFOT this was written on ASP.Net 2, MVC 1 and is a total hack - I'm reflecting out their anti forgery token stuff, but it's all private methods. The chances are that this will need a bit of an update with each new version of ASP and MVC, download the MVC 3 source and see how the methods have changed - if we're very lucky they might even have exposed them so that WebForms can use them.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm going to have a look at the latest MVC source this weekend to see if I can work it out. Please feel free to post a revised version of your above code if have some free time. ;)

Comment: See my post; there's a new supported helper that you can use to get the functionality in your webforms pages.

Comment: @BFOT @pvanhouten has a better way in MVC3, there's a fully supported `AntiForgery.GetHtml()` method built in now. My solution is a shim for MVC1-2 only.

Answer (score 22):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into this issue today and thought I'd share.  I'm working in MVC4 and have a webform control (.ascx) that's shared between both MVC (via RenderPartial) and WebForms.  In that control, I needed an antiforgery token.  Fortunately, there's a helper now you can use in your webforms now that's as simple as this:

```
<%= AntiForgery.GetHtml() %>
```

This will render your anti-forgery token like you would get in MVC.

[Here's the MS link to it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg537903%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

Comment: Excellent, this is a better way to solve the problem in WebForms 2/MVC 3 and above.

Answer (score 1):

By default, ASP.NET WebForms already include measures to validate events and viewstate. [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/02/csrf-webforms.aspx) talks a little bit about that in the linked post. XSRF mitigation strategies are talked about [here (Scott Hanselman)](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ViewStateUserKeyMakesViewStateMoreTamperresistant.aspx) and [here (Dino Esposito)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972969.aspx)

Comment: Very good links, thanks.  I was hoping for a way to use the AntiForgeryToken specifically, because the "consumer" of the MVC web service is on a WebForms page (that I will not be rewriting in MVC.)

Answer (score 0):

you could create a new HtmlHelper in your controller and then pull the anti xrsf from there:

```
var htmlHelper = new HtmlHelper(
    new ViewContext(
        ControllerContext, 
        new WebFormView("omg"), 
        new ViewDataDictionary(), 
        new TempDataDictionary()), 
        new ViewPage());

var xsrf = htmlHeler.AntiForgeryToken;

myObject.XsrfToken = xsrf;

return JsonResult(myObject);
```

Comment: It is my understanding that the AntiForgeryToken sets a cookie, and injects a hidden form field, so the two can be compared.  How does this accomplish that?