# AntiForgeryToken with multiple ajax forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC4 page that allows a logged in user to update various profile elements (username, password, cc#).  I would like to use the AntiForgeryToken, but in that only a part of the page is updated when any given form is submitted, the tokens created for the other form elements are invalid after one of them is used.  How can I make this work.

The error returned upon submitting a second form is:

"The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "xxxxxxxxx-0gf5izjl-", but the current user is "xxxx-EjRYaQ7asdfV@test.com"

Thanks

Comment: I believe you will find your answer in question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096769/antiforgerytoken-invalid-after-sign-in

Comment: I think you're right - feel free to add that as an answer so I can select it