# How to include the @Html.AntiForgeryToken() when deleting an object using a Delete link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, antiforgerytoken

i have the following `ajax.actionlink` which calls a `Delete action method` for deleting an object:-

```
 @if (!item.IsAlreadyAssigned(item.LabTestID))
        { 
        string i = "Are You sure You want to delete (" + @item.Description.ToString() + ") ?";
           @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete",
       "Delete", "LabTest",
      new { id = item.LabTestID },

new AjaxOptions
{ Confirm = i,
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    OnSuccess = "deletionconfirmation",
    OnFailure = "deletionerror"
})
}
```

**but is there a way to include `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` with the `Ajax.actionlink` deletion call to make sure that no attacker can send a false deletion request?**

BR

Answer (score 17):

You need to use the `Html.AntiForgeryToken` helper which sets a cookie and emits a hidden field with the same value. When sending the AJAX request you need to add this value to the POST data as well.

So I would use a normal link instead of an Ajax link:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Delete", 
    "Delete", 
    "LabTest", 
    new { 
        id = item.LabTestID
    }, 
    new { 
        @class = "delete",
        data_confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete (" + item.Description.ToString() + ") ?"
    }
)
```

and then put the hidden field somewhere in the DOM (for example before the closing body tag):

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

and finally unobtrusively AJAXify the delete anchor:

```
$(function () {
    $('.delete').click(function () {
        if (!confirm($(this).data('confirm'))) {
            return false;
        }

        var token = $(':input:hidden[name*="RequestVerificationToken"]');
        var data = { };
        data[token.attr('name')] = token.val();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {

            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Now you could decorate your `Delete` action with the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply ,, so there is not way to define this in the original Ajax.Actionlink?.

Comment: And i have a second concern, about why all the examples on the internet only use the antiforgery token in the edit and create scenarios (not in the deletion scenario), while i did not see any tutorial that uses the antiforgery token in the delete scenario ,, so is it necessary to do so (i think that we should do so !!!)

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the answer by [Bronx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074199/jquery-ajax-calls-and-the-html-antiforgerytoken/12116344#12116344):

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, localOptions, jqXHR) {
    var token, tokenQuery;
    if (options.type.toLowerCase() !== 'get') {
        token = GetAntiForgeryToken();
        if (options.data.indexOf(token.name)===-1) {
            tokenQuery = token.name + '=' + token.value;
            options.data = options.data ? (options.data + '&' + tokenQuery) 
                : tokenQuery;
        }
    }
});
```

combined with this answer by [Jon White](http://jonwhite.me/2012/09/16/how-to-use-antiforgery-tokens-with-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc/)

```
function GetAntiForgeryToken() {
  var tokenField = $("input[type='hidden'][name$='RequestVerificationToken']");
  if (tokenField.length == 0) { return null; 
  } else {
  return {
     name: tokenField[0].name,
     value: tokenField[0].value
  };
}
```

Edit
sorry - realised I am re-inventing the wheel here [SO asp-net-mvc-antiforgerytoken-over-ajax/16495855#16495855](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346070/asp-net-mvc-antiforgerytoken-over-ajax/16495855#16495855)