# ActionMethod cannot be found by ActionLink - ajax.ActionLink()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I've got a trouble with execute ajaxified HttpPost action method. Breakpoint in ActionMethod Publish isn't even fire, Html version of this method return: resource cannot be found (404). The name of the controller is okay, logged in user's role is okay, PartialView exists. What can be a reason?

This is a view:

```
<div id="info"></div>


    @if (User.IsInRole("admin") && item.IsPublished == false)
    {
        <p>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Publish", "Publish", new { id = item.RecommendationID }, new AjaxOptions() { Confirm="Are you sure?", HttpMethod="POST", UpdateTargetId="info" })
        </p>
    }
```

This is Action Method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Publish(int? id) 
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        Recommendation recommendation = db.Recommendations.Find(id);

        if (recommendation == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        recommendation.IsPublished = true;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return PartialView("RecommendationPublished");
    }
```

Edit: Okay - now I know that HttpPost attribute caused my problem - with HttpGet works properly. But in that shape this operation will be insecure (updating database field). How to write it and maintain safety rules?

Comment: Make sure you have `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` referenced. Also, try removing the `AntiForgeryToken`. You can't really use it with `Ajax.ActionLink`. You'll need to use a regular `ActionLink` and some javascript to grab the forgery token and put it with the `POST` request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot use the AntiForgeryToken along with the Ajax.ActionLink. You'll need to parse the forgery token with some javascript and append it to your post request.

[How to include the @Html.AntiForgeryToken() when deleting an object using a Delete link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273404/how-to-include-the-html-antiforgerytoken-when-deleting-an-object-using-a-dele)

If you don't want that, remove the forgery token. Also make sure you're using `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've referenced jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js. Tried call without AntiForgeryToken, but still doesn't work. It seems like something with communication between view and controller, because 'Publish' Action Method isn't even started (as I mentioned above - breakpoint isn't fired and error 404 is returned)...