# Does the AntiForgeryToken need to be inside a form tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

All the examples I see have seen, have the AntiForgeryToken inside of a `<form>` tag:

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("DoThis", "FromHere", FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "MyId"})
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
End Using
```

Is that required? I am doing posts back to the server using ajax/jQuery calls. I'm using the example provided here ([preFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346070/asp-net-mvc-antiforgerytoken-over-ajax)) so that I can retrieve the AntiForgeryToken. I just don't have my AntyForgeryToken inside of a form tag. I just placed it on my root _Layout page and called it good. Why would I need to do anything else? I can't think of why I have to...

Comment: AntiForgeryToken is useful for security reasons (it helps preventing Cross Site Scripting).
If you don't care or don't need to secure your app (local app, intranet, etc...) then you don't need it.
Have a look at http://www.devcurry.com/2013/01/what-is-antiforgerytoken-and-why-do-i.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the examples they have the anti-forgery within the form tag, so when the form is posted via a submit button click it will automatically get posted with all of the other form variables.  If you are manually posting the data via ajax you can have the anti-forgery token generated anywhere, but you will need to grab that value and post it along with any other data you are sending to the server.

Make sure you name the property of the anti-forgery token the same as the HTML helper method does ("__RequestVerificationToken").

Comment: Well, I'm not naming the anti-forgery token as I'm letting the html helper handle it. And that's what I thought, I just wanted a clear answer, thanks @MDiesel!